# jQuery .find() 2 matching arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an unordered list with multiple properties per element and I want to find all elements that have both properties.

```
var results = $('#mylist').find(function() {
    return
        $(this).attr('data-label') == 'red' &&
        $(this).attr('data-size') == 1;
});
```

I attached an example in the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/nbz4H/1/

Comment: FYI, `find` does not accept a function. Maybe you meant `filter`.

Comment: Just a pointer, but if you're using jQuery you should select jQuery from the `select` drop-down element on the left of the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbz4H/13/) page...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a single selector:

```
$('li[data-label="red"][data-size="1"]').css('color','red');
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/RyR87/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't take a function as a parameter. That's why this doesn't work.

What you need is to construct an appropriate CSS [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Something like:

```
 results = $('#mylist [data-label="red"][data-size="1"]');
```